# error in formatting date in bash

Tags: bash

I have this date "05/11/2015 23:45" expressed as "dd/mm/YY H:M" to which I would like to add a certain span of time, let's say 2 days.

When I try to execute these command I got the following results:

```
date_time_start=`date -d "05/11/2015 23:45" +%d/%m/%Y" "%H:%M` 
echo $date_time_start
11/05/2015 23:45
```

the order has been inverted between day and month

Now if I do:

```
date_time_end=`date -d "$date_time_start 2 day" +%d/%m/%Y" "%H:%M`
echo $date_time_end
07/11/2015 23:45
```

the 2 days have been correctly addded and the order is d/m/Y!

Could you please tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first observation is wrong. When you have a date "05/11/2015" and pass it as input to date, it will be read in the form "mm/dd/YY". The form +"%d/%m/%Y" is the form of the output for the date utility, so your first output seems right, because you just swap month and day.

But in the second step month and day are swapped again while 05 is interpreted as day. So the calculation is right because of a double swap error.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is that +"&d/%m/%Y %H:%M" is going to tell it the format to read in the date in that format, but it's to output the date in that format.  It will be read in as m/d/Y H:M using that format.  (also, quote the whole string, not the space).  This misunderstanding has caused all your confusion

Answer (score 1):

You need the input in a format that avoids bad interpretations.
The date you have in text as: `05/11/2015 23:45` is interpreted by date as `m/d/Y` (the USA way to write dates).

```
$ date -ud "05/11/2015 23:45"
Mon May 11 23:45:00 UTC 2015
```

It is clear that the `05` is being read by `date` as `May` (the fifth month of the year), not as a day.

Then, when you set the **output** format, the error is repeated:

```
$ date -d "05/11/2015 23:45" +%d/%m/%Y" "%H:%M
11/05/2015 23:45
```

And the month is presented as `05` (not what you want of month `11`).

Sadly, there is no other solution than to create a date either in the format that an USA centric developer have defined:

```
$ date -ud "11/05/2015 23:45"
Thu Nov  5 23:45:00 UTC 2015
```

or in a reversed kind of international accepted way:

```
$ date -ud "2015/11/05 23:45"
Thu Nov  5 23:45:00 UTC 2015
```

Either way, you need to change the string of date you have.

Then, you can add two days:

```
$ date -ud "2015/11/05 23:45 2days" +%d/%m/%Y" "%H:%M
07/11/2015 23:45
```

I'll insist in recommending you to use `2015/11/05` to avoid date issues.

```
$ date -ud "2015/11/05 23:45 2days" +%Y/%m/%d" "%H:%M
2015/11/07 23:45
```

Comment: your explanation is clear, I got the problem. i will follow your suggetion in using USA format